# How to hide groups from res.user form in odoo 9?

Tags: xml, python-2.7, odoo-9

see the below image. I want to hide groups under Other tab. How to do this?

[Click Here to see Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/izgib.png)

Answer (score 0):

Activate the developer mode and go to Settings > Groups and delete unnecessary group!

Comment: No, I dont want to delete the groups. Actually the user creation form is called from 2 places. So if it is called from second place, then I want to hide these groups otherwise it should display the form as it is

Comment: When it is called from another place at that place hide that by managing some check box.